# python is not logging all content to file

Tags: python

I want to log the script output to a file while still displaying the output to the screen.
It works fine, except for some cases where not all the content is written to the file (one or two lines can be missed, if the output is long)
Below is my code:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush()

write_log = open("log.txt", 'a', 0)
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, write_log)
sys.stderr = Tee(sys.stderr, write_log)
```

Tried all the following options at the end of the code, but the result is the same:

```
os.fsync(write_log.fileno())
write_log.flush()
write_log.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't each `Tee` open the file independently?

Comment: Hello, I tried to open the file independently, but the result is the same. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `with` statement or use `try-except` and explicitly close the file.

Comment: Hi, I'm using write_log.close() at the end of the script, so the files does get closed (I verified using write_log.closed and it returns True).